# How do I convert binary data into an image and display them in a picturebox?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have an image in an access file, and I want to retrieve and display it in another Windows Forms form using the user id.

Code to save the image:

```
 Dim img = PictureBox1. Image

 Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
 img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat)
 img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
 bytImage = ms.ToArray()
 ms.Close()
```

Code to retrieve the image:

```
 con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

 con.Open()
 Dim userIdPro = Transfer.userIdPro
 Dim query = ("SELECT Image FROM User_info WHERE ID = " & userIdPro & ";")

 Dim ds As New DataSet

 Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
 Dim cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con)
 dr = cm.ExecuteReader
 While dr.Read()
     Dim MyByte = dr.Item("Value")
     Dim fs = New MemoryStream
     fs.Write(MyByte, 0, MyByte.Length)
     fs.Flush()
     Dim MyImg = Image.FromStream(fs, True)
     MyImg.Save(dr.Item("ID").ToString & ".JPG", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        PictureBox1.Image = MyImg
        fs.Close()
        fs = Nothing
     End While
     con.Close()
End Sub
```

I can't bring the binary data into `dr`; it is always empty.

Comment: Where's the code that saves the Images in the database? Then, you have `SELECT Image FROM User_info`, but you're trying to get `Value` and `ID`. Maybe you wanted to write `SELECT * FROM User_info` instead? The format of the field where the image is stored and the method used to store it are relevant details.

Comment: Btw, `img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat)` and `img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg)` cannot live in the same `MemoryStream` loft.

Comment: @Jimi i was trying to display only image from my table according to the user.My table also contains other field according to the user id. and the field image is ole object format in  database.

Comment: Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat)
        img. Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        bytImage = ms.ToArray()
        ms.Close()

Comment: While inserting the type of the image is byte

Comment: You're saving (trying to) the Image to a MemoryStream, twice. You can't do that. But you're never saving it to the database, just assinging the byte array to a variable. -- Your table may have more than one field, but you asking to retrieve just one of them here: `"SELECT Image FROM User_info`: just the `Image` field. -- If it's MS Access, the field's data type is quite relevant, as it is the method used to store the Image.

Comment: @Jimi i save it in another in a button click event. Cant i call only one table field. And another problem is i dont why i cant hold the image in the dr. Read() everytime its empty

Answer (score 1):

I put your code calling the function bytesToImage(...)`. You don't need to save the image locally, unless you have a reason to do it.

```
 con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

 con.Open()
 Dim userIdPro = Transfer.userIdPro

 // Don't concatenate your parameters. This is a bad practice and
 // exposes your application to SQL injection attacks. Use SQL
 // parameters instead.

 Dim query = ("SELECT Image FROM User_info WHERE ID = " & userIdPro & ";")

 Dim ds As New DataSet

 Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
 Dim cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con)
 dr = cm.ExecuteReader
 While dr.Read()

     Dim MyByte = dr.Item("Value")
     Dim MyImg As Image

     If MyByte IsNot Nothing Then
        // You do not need to save it, just convert to an image
        // type and set it to your PictureBox1 control.

        MyImg = bytesToImage(MyByte)
        PictureBox1.Image = MyImg
     End If
End While
con.Close()
```

You class should have the `Image` property as `Byte()`

```
<Table("User_info")>
Public Class User

   Public Property Photo As Byte()

End Class
```

Using the following functions:

```
Public Function imageToBytes(ByVal imageIn As System.Drawing.Image) As Byte()
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Return ms.ToArray()
End Function

Public Function bytesToImage(ByVal byteArrayIn As Byte()) As Image
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(byteArrayIn)
    Dim returnImage As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    Return returnImage
End Function
```

To save the image into the database:

```
Public Sub SaveImage()
    Using context = New ProjectDb()
        Dim user = New User() With {
            .Id = Guid.NewGuid,
            .Photo = imageToBytes(PictureBox1.Image)
        }
        context.Users.Add(user)
        context.SaveChanges()
    End Using
End Sub
```

To fetch the image from the database:

```
Public Function GetImage(ByVal id As Guid) As Image
    Using context = New ProjectDb()

        Dim image As Image

        Dim user As User = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Id = id)

        If user IsNot Nothing Then
            image = bytesToImage(user.Photo)
            PictureBox2.Image = image
        End If

    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i found another way by using path.
@Jimi i have a question for you it would be great if you helped.
when user enters his images in the database his path is saved but i want when the user insert picture to copy that file into a folder and then insert the path of my folder into the database.